# How to make a compiled Regexp a global variable?

Tags: rust

I have several regular expressions that are defined at runtime and I would like to make them global variables.

To give you an idea, the following code works:

```
use regex::Regex; // 1.1.5

fn main() {
    let RE = Regex::new(r"hello (\w+)!").unwrap();
    let text = "hello bob!\nhello sue!\nhello world!\n";
    for cap in RE.captures_iter(text) {
        println!("your name is: {}", &cap[1]);
    }
}
```

But I would like it to be something like this:

```
use regex::Regex; // 1.1.5

static RE: Regex = Regex::new(r"hello (\w+)!").unwrap();

fn main() {
    let text = "hello bob!\nhello sue!\nhello world!\n";
    for cap in RE.captures_iter(text) {
        println!("your name is: {}", &cap[1]);
    }
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
error[E0015]: calls in statics are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants
 --> src/main.rs:3:20
  |
3 | static RE: Regex = Regex::new(r"hello (\w+)!").unwrap();
  |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Does this mean that I need nightly Rust in order to make these variables global, or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use the [lazy_static](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static) macro like this:

```
use lazy_static::lazy_static; // 1.3.0
use regex::Regex; // 1.1.5

lazy_static! {
    static ref RE: Regex = Regex::new(r"hello (\w+)!").unwrap();
}

fn main() {
    let text = "hello bob!\nhello sue!\nhello world!\n";
    for cap in RE.captures_iter(text) {
        println!("your name is: {}", &cap[1]);
    }
}
```

If you are using the 2015 edition of Rust, you can still use `lazy_static` via:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;
```

Comment: @huon Good point. This is because Regex implements Deref correct?

Comment: @squiguy, no (Regex doesn't implement Deref): it's because `lazy_static!` allows you to assign any expression of the right type to the `static ref`, and `Regex::new(...).unwrap()` has type `Regex`.

Comment: In actual implementation I did even better. I created a `make_regex` function and assigned directly to the output. Very convenient!

Comment: @vitiral Could you please post your solution as an answer too?

Comment: It's not really generic. I was simply pointing out that you can use functions (or any other rust construct) using lazy_static. This might even be outdated, you may be able to make true `const` types now (not sure)